# Meaning of "not all horses are Trojan horses"

Tags: meaning-in-context, jokes

In this standup [comedy](https://youtu.be/R3FDoW565Lc?t=636)(around 10:39 in the link):

He said: "Not all horses are Trojan horses".

What does it mean here? I know what Trojan horse is literally but doesn't see why horse is brought up here.

Answer (score 0):

> So it turns out, not all horses are Trojan horses.
>
> I know that now.
>
> That was a messy afternoon.

The joke here is that someone gave him a horse, which he assumed was a Trojan horse, so he cut it open to get at the soldiers hiding inside. But it turned out to be a real horse, and he had killed it and made a mess.

Comment: Where is it mentioned that someone give him a horse?

Comment: @CYC He doesn’t say it directly, but “that was a messy afternoon” doesn’t make sense unless someone gave him a horse.

Comment: Or unless he came across one. But traditionally, a Trojan horse is a gift. "beware of Greeks bearing gifts"